# Copy only *.h files with subfolders structure bash

Tags: bash, ditto

I need to write a script to copy only *.h files with saving the folder structure:

now it looks like this:

```
cd "${SRCROOT}"
echo 'Copying Cocos Headers into Framework..'
cd ..
for H in `find ./Frameworks/Cocos -name "*.h"`;  do
echo "${H}"  
ditto -V "${H}" "${BUILD_DIR}/include/header/cocos/"

done
```

but the files are in one folder, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux `find` can be really powerful.

You can use

```
OutDir="${BUILD_DIR}/include/header/cocos/" # Linux is case sensitive, Check if
mkdir -p "${OutDir}"                        # it is needed Cocos or cocos...
cd ./Frameworks/Cocos                       # just to have clean path to create

# Here with only one line 
find . -name "*.h" -exec bash -c 'cp -p --parents {} "${OutDir}" ' \;
# cd - # Eventually to come back to the previous path
```

Notes:
  `cp -p` preserve ownership...
  `cp --parents`create destination dir but needs that the base directory it exists.
  `mkdir -p` Create the directory with all the parents' path without error if just exists
  `man find` for all the options of find.

---

If you want to remain close to the precedent script

```
cd "${SRCROOT}"
echo 'Copying Cocos Headers into Framework..'
StartSearchDir="${SRCROOT}../Frameworks/Cocos"
BaseDestDir="${BUILD_DIR}/include/header/cocos/"
cd $StartSearchDir
for H in `find . -name "*.h"`;  do
  echo "${H}" 
  PathFileDir=$(dirname $H)
  mkdir -p "${BUILD_DIR}/${PathFileDir}"     # no error, make parents too
  cp -p "$H" "${BUILD_DIR}/${PathFileDir}/"    # preserve ownership...
  # ditto -V "${H}" "${BUILD_DIR}/include/header/cocos/" # commented line
done
```

Note with `dirname` you can extract from a full path+filename string only the path.
Check the help with `man dirname` and `man basename`

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue this way:

```
cd "${SRCROOT}"
echo 'Copying Cocos Headers into Framework..'

StartSearchDir="${SRCROOT}/../Frameworks/Cocos"
BaseDestDir="${BUILD_DIR}/include/${PRODUCT_NAME}/header/cocos/"

echo 'STARTDIR:'$StartSearchDir
echo 'DESTDIR:'$BaseDestDir

cd $StartSearchDir

tar -cf - . | (cd $BaseDestDir ; tar -xpf - --include='*.h')
```

But Hastur solution is nice too - make his solution as the best one

Comment: Creative woraround :)